# Integral of $\sin(x)\cdot x^n$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

The integral is as:

> $$\int_0^\infty\sin\left(x\right)\times x^{n}\;\mathbb{d}x$$
>   Where $n\in\mathfrak{R}$.

I was able to find the convergence of this integral using Dirichlet's test, which implied $-2<n<0$.

But the hard part is to find the value of this integral for me.
Wolfram alpha gives the answer as:
[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28t%29*t^c+from+t%3D0+to+t%3Dinfinity](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28t%29*t%5Ec+from+t%3D0+to+t%3Dinfinity)

Which is very close to gamma function. So i tried to assume integral of form $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ix}\times x^n\;\mathbb{d}x$$

So that i would take the $-\mathfrak{Im}$ part of this integral. But I still have no idea how to evaluate this.

Comment: Use integration via parts thats all by LIATE rule

Comment: Sorry i kinda don't understand let us assume there's no bound for n. Even then we can only go upto integral part of n, the fraction part will create trouble.